# jQueryMobile: Right Margin on a ListView

Tags: jquery, listview, jquery-mobile

I have a simple `listview` in jQueryMobile which fills the width of the screen (default behavior).

How can I have it render so that there is a `50px margin` on the right side of the list? The resulting `listview` structure would look slightly off center to the left (that's desired)

Comment: can you try by adding data-inset="true"  to the ul?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add that CSS to the `<ul data-role="listview">` element:

```
<ul data-role="listview" style="margin-right: 50px">
    ...
</ul>
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jasper/HjurM/

You can also target this element in your CSS style-sheet rather than using inline CSS:

```
.ui-page .ui-content .ui-listview {
    margin-right : 50px;
}​
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jasper/HjurM/1/

Of course the easiest way to target the element via CSS would be to give it an ID and target that ID:

```
#my-offset-ul {
    margin-right : 50px;
}
```

### Update

You can target the filter search bar like this:

```
.ui-page .ui-content .ui-listview-filter {
    margin-right : 50px;
}​
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jasper/HjurM/3/

Comment: That worked great, but the SearchBar on the ListView is still wide, is there a setting that will do the full ListView?

Comment: @BahaiResearch.com Check-out the last **update** in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use data-role="content" on your data-role="page" and the elements will no longer fill the width of the screen but have a nice standard 20px margin all around.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geoyws/U54AE/1/)

```
<div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="content">
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
            <li>1st Item</li>
            <li>2nd Item</li>
            <li>3rd Item</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

But data-role="content" is [deprecated](http://jquerymobile.com/upgrade-guide/1.4/#content) now. So we are left with:

Old:

```
<div data-role="content">
</div>
```

New:

```
<div class="ui-content" role="main">
</div>
```